# User account control Windows - Run as administrator broken

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-10, uac

So far, this issue occurs on 3 different systems. Windows 10, Server 2012 and Server 2016 (I suspect this is also the case on windows 8 as server 2012 is basically the same thing but not used it).

**State**:

- GPO enabled for UAC
- GPO set UAC to never notify
- User is in groups BUILTIN\Adminstrators, Domain Admins, Administrators
- Domain Admins are a member of the local machine administrators group

**Issue**:

Running application by double clicking, for example an MSI file which requires admin priveleges, file attempts to run and fails.

Run application by right clicking and choosing run as administrator, message states administrative priveleges required to run as administrator

The following also does not work: runas /user:DOMAIN\ADMINUSER application

**Temporary resolution** (not good enough):

Run command prompt as administrator (why this allows to be run as administrator I have no idea). Run file.

If I can find a common application to test with, I will post it in an edit.

Comment: If UAC is changed in the GPO to notify, does it prompt you with a "yes/no" option running the application? Or try temporarily disabling UAC and enabling it again. I'm assuming that you are logged in as one of the administrators also correct?

Comment: As soon as this instance occurs next, I will try. We are in the midst of updating all systems to Windows 10 1703 (nightmare in itself). I'll let you know as soon as I can.

Comment: Can you provide us a screenshot of the User Account Control part of your GPO? because there are a lot of available values for each options and we don't really know which one you chose.

Comment: UAC `Behaviour of prompt - Elevate without prompting: enabled`, `Detect App installs and prompt: disabled`, `Only elevate UIAccess apps installed in secure locations: disabled`, `Run all admins in admin approval mode: enabled`. Rest is left undefined

Comment: Does Shift + Right Click, Run as Different User, enter admin credentials, work?

Comment: No. I have found that I have to open an admin command prompt to start up the odd problematic apps. I had one the other day but forgot I had posted this thread. Since then I have downgraded my work machine back to the what I think is the best Windows OS (7)